# What if Upvote on Comments raising reputation?

Tags: feature-request

If I'm not wrong, I've seen somewhere (can't remember, where) that, an upvote on comment raises the reputation with +2. If it's never implemented, that can be implemented, because:

- There are many comments, that satisfy the question-asker as an accepted answer for his/her question.
- A comment upvote doesn't mean a Facebook "like" button.

Therefore, an upvote to good comment can raise the reputation with +2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. We don’t want to encourage answers hidden in comments or comments in general.
2. Some comments get upvotes because they are funny or point out a side problem.

These upvotes don’t mean anything, and they shouldn’t be treated as if they do. Also, you cannot downvote a comment, so this would be unfair: you could write *something* without the risk to lose reputation.

Comment: Well said, especially *"so this would be unfair: you could write something without the risk to lose reputation"*. Kudos.